# url amigable desde formulario laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo la siguiente url con multiples filtros dados desde un formulario

https://localhost/productos?nombre_producto=&continente=

la url se ve de esa forma pero no logro que se vea de esta forma

https://localhost/producto/continente

estoy usando esto pero no funciona ya que como no es una url si no un request

```
Route::get('/productos/{nombre_producto?}/{continente?}', 'ProductosController@GeneralProductos');
```

Answer (score 0):

La única manera de pasar data mediante un método `GET` es mediante query params (como lo estás haciendo):

Endpoint:

```
 GET https://localhost/productos?nombre_producto=un_nombre&continente=un_continente
```

Si lo que deseas es "ocultar" esa información de la vista, solo se me ocurre hacer la llamada mediante `POST` enviando los parámetros en el body.

Endpoint:

```
POST https://localhost/productos
```

Headers:

```
Content-type: Application/json
```

Body:

```
{
  "nombre_producto" : "el nombre",
  "continente" : "un continente"
}
```

Obviamente, no es recomedable hacer llamadas `POST` solo para consultar datos, se recomienda hacerlas mediante `GET` a través de query params.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución posible seria mediante POST llamar a una función que cree la ruta GET que deseas ejemplo rapido:

Rutas :

```
Route::post('/productos', 'ProductosController@buscar')->name('buscar');
Route::get('/productos/{nombre_producto?}/{continente?}', 'ProductosController@buscador')->name('buscador');
```

Controlador :

```
 public function buscar(Request $request){
        return redirect()->route('buscador' , ['nombre_producto' => $request->nombre_producto, 'continente' => $request->continente]);
 }
 public function buscador(Request $request){
        $continente = $request->continente;
        $producto = $request->nombre_producto
        // Logica deseada
 }
```

Blade :

```
<form action="{{route('buscar')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="nombre_producto">
    <input type="text" name="continente">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```